# Akka-Streams collecting data (Source -> Flow -> Flow (collect) -> Sink)

Tags: scala, akka-stream

I'm totally new in Scala and Akka. I've a simple RunnableFlow:

```
Source -> Flow (do some transformation) -> Sink.runForeach
```

Now I want something like this:

```
Source -> Flow1 (do some transformation) -> Flow2 (do some transformation) -> Sink.runForeach
```

But Flow2 should wait until 100 elements from Flow1 are available and then transform these 100 elements to a new element (which needs all 100 elements from Flow1) and give this new element to the Sink.

I did some research and found [Explicit user defined buffers](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0-M2/scala/stream-rate.html) but I don´t understand how I can access all 100 elements from flow1 in flow2 and do some transformation with them. Can someone explain it? Or even better post a small simple example ? Or both?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Akka Defined Collection**

If you don't mind using an akka determined collection type then you can use the `grouped` function instead:

```
//alternative stream formation
val stream = Source(1 to 100).via(Flow[Int].grouped(bufferSize))
                             .runWith(Sink foreach println)
```

**User Defined Collection**

If you want to control the type of collection used for your buffer, e.g. a `Seq` or `Array`:

```
type MyCollectionType[X] = Array[X]

def emptyMyCollection[X] : MyCollectionType[X] = Array.empty[X]
```

Then you can perform this operation with two Flows.  The first Flow executes a `scan` to build up a sequence of elements:

```
val bufferSize = 10

def appendToMyCollection[X](coll : MyCollectionType[X], i : X) : MyCollectionType[X] = 
  (if(coll.size < bufferSize) coll else emptyMyCollection[Int]) :+ i

val buffer : Flow[Int, MyCollectionType[Int], _] = 
  Flow[Int].scan[MyCollectionType[Int]](emptyMyCollection[Int]){
    (coll, i) => appendToMyCollection(coll, i)
  }
```

The second Flow is a `filter` for a sequence with just the right size (i.e. "goldiLocks"):

```
val goldiLocks : Flow[MyCollectionType[Int], MyCollectionType[Int],_] =
  Flow[MyCollectionType[Int]].filter(_.size == bufferSize)
```

These two Flows can be combined to produce a Stream which will generate the desired collection type:

```
val stream = Source(1 to 100).via(buffer)
                             .via(goldiLocks)
                             .runWith(Sink foreach println)
```

Comment: `Flow[Int].grouped(bufferSize)` is simpler.